# Finding the limit of an sequence defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm looking for a manner to calculate that limit :

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\int^j_{0}re^{-\frac{2j^2}{(j-r)(j+r)}}\frac{(4r^2j^4+4r^4j^2-4j^6+r^2j^8-4r^4j^6+6r^6j^4-4r^8j^2+r^{10})^2}{j^2(j^2-r^2)^8}\,dr$$

Comment: $\infty$ (and if the denominator is $j^{\ \color{red}{6}}(j^2-r^2)^8$, then the limit is $1/(8e^2)$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.